# SSL with docker elastic beastalk intance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Nestjs application which is deployed with Docker on an Elastik beanstalk service.
Among the incoming rules of my security group I have port 80 and 443.
I created a subdomain and redirected to my application url with CNAME.
I generated an SSL certificate with ACM and validated with the provided CNAME and it validated fine.

My application works with the url in HTTP but not in HTTPS.

I know how to do it with a nodejs application, I just have to go to my environment configuration and go to load balancer but with Docker, I don't have the possibility to do it directly in the environment.

I have create a Application load balancer and i have add port 80 and 443 with rules and target group listen port 80 in my application (status healthy green)

[image]

[image]

[image]

My security group allow 443
[image]
[image]

My subdomain http work but my https not working.

Comment: Is the security group in your screenshot assigned to the EC2 instance, or the Load Balancer? You need to open port `443` in the Load Balancer's security group, not the EC2 instance's security group.

Answer (score 3):

I think application load balancer security group will block the HTTPS traffic if not allowed. I suggest to check Security Group which is attached to Load balancer.